# Android monits Volley Request

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using your library volley request in android by Monits: https://github.com/Monits/volley-requests

my code like below:

RESTFull api 
url: http://192.168.100.11/v1/login
method: post
params: email & password

the response json format:

```
{

  “error”: false

  “name”: “sokhorn”

  “email”: “sokhorn.h@gmail.com”

  “apiKey”: “a7c09f87e3c4bd55e017115bfbcf0d84”

 “createdAt”: “2016–06–01 08:52:58”
}
```

android code

```
Gson gson;
Rest.setBaseUrl("http://192.168.100.11");
Rest.setGson(gson);
Rest.one("login")
        .post(User.class)
        .query("email", "sokhorn.h@gmail.com")
        .query("password", "q1w2e3r4t5")
        .request();
```

question:

how can I get value from response?

Would you give me full coding sample of how to use volley?

thanks,

Comment: what is User.class and definition?

Comment: check the library documentation. you should get your answers

Comment: checked, but I can't. Please help me.

Comment: check this link for more to learn : https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Comment: Hello sir, your link is for built in volley in android. but in above code is for volley request created by Monits based on android built in volley. Would you please correct my code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your User.class must be

```
public class User {
    private String error;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String apiKey;
    private String createdAt;

    public String getEmail (){
        return this.email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }
```

}

To make the request you must have a User instance that already has the email and password.

Now your android code for the request must be:

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); //Use the instance of your gson
Rest.setBaseUrl("http://192.168.100.11/v1");
Rest.setGson(gson);

Rest.one("login")
    .post(user) //This is the user instance that I told you above
    .onSuccess(new Response.Listener<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(User userResponse) {
            //Handle your response
        }
    })
    .onError(new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            //Handle error
        }
    })
    .onCancel(new ListenableRequest.CancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            //Handle cancel event
        }
    })
    .request();
```

The success, error and cancel listeners are optionals.

In case the **v1** is not part of your base url your code must be

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); //Use the instance of your gson
Rest.setBaseUrl("http://192.168.100.11");
Rest.setGson(gson);

Rest.one("v1", "login")
    .post(user) //This is the user instance that I told you above
    .onSuccess(new Response.Listener<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(User userResponse) {
            //Handle your response
        }
    })
    .onError(new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            //Handle error
        }
    })
    .onCancel(new ListenableRequest.CancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            //Handle cancel event
        }
    })
    .request();
```